# Node.js with Express and Socket.IO refuses more than one connection

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I am trying to set up a Node web server with Express and Socket.IO. I have the static page feature of Express working fine, however, if I try to connect a Socket.IO client to the server, all subsequent connection attempts are refused, and the client socket never fires the `connect` event.

The code used to set up the server:

```
let app = Express();
let port = options.port || 4747;
let serverOptions = {};

if ( options.ssl ) {
    if ( !options.ssl.key || !options.ssl.cert ) {
        throw "You must specify the path to both the private key file and the certificate in the SSL options";
    }

    console.log( "SSL enabled...loading keyfile and certificate." );
    Object.assign( serverOptions, {
        key: Fs.readFileSync( options.ssl.key ),
        cert: Fs.readFileSync( options.ssl.cert )
    } );
}

webServer.server = Https.createServer( serverOptions, app );

app.use( "/", Express.static( options.webRoot || "www", {
    index: "index.htm"
} ) );

console.log( `Web server listening on port ${ port }...` );
webServer.server.listen( port );
```

The code to set up the socket (imports the above as `WebServer` and SocketIO as `Io`):

```
WebServer( WebConfig );
Io( WebServer.server );
```

My test client is simply:

```
var s = require( "socket.io-client" )( "https://arcanox.me:4747/" );

s.on( "connect", function() { 
    console.log( "Connected!" );
} );
```

It never prints "Connected!", but while it is running, all subsequent attempts to connect (including just for static content) are rejected with `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

What gives?

Comment: Can you please add io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket){ console.log('connected')}  event to your server js file?

Comment: I may have figured it out. For some reason unless I put a `console.log` before the socket connection listener was set up, it wasn't logging anything into journalctl (this is running as a systemd service) when it crashed. There was a module error in the connection listener which was restarting node as soon as it accepted a connection.